Optimize tensorflow library disk size in production
I'm using tensorflow to load keras model and run predict.
Something like this
import tensorflow as tf
import cv2
from keras.preprocessing import image
import numpy as np
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web

model = tf.keras.models.load_model('my_model.keras')
model.summary()

I want to deploy this code to vercel.com (free plan) but got this error Size of uploaded file exceeds 300MB. I thought it's because of tf library is too big. Is there anyway to fix this?
